# Handling presence in Strophe.js-based chat application

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe

Is there any existing solution which provides the presence handling for chat app based on Strophe.js?

I have simple chat application based on Strophe.js. I'd like to show only the users who are online and dynamicaly alter the list. I was wondering whether there is any existing solution (possibly Strophe plugin) which handles this. If there's no such thing, what's the best/simplest way to implement it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By using Strophe, you can just send an IQ to your server that asks for your roster list like so:

```
iq = $iq({type: 'get'}).c('query', {xmlns: 'jabber:iq:roster'});
App.connection.sendIQ(iq, your_roster_callback_function);
```

This would query your server for your rosters and would return an object containing your roster list. You can then iterate through your rosters like:

```
your_roster_callback_function(iq){
  $(iq).find('item').each(function(){
    var jid = $(this).attr('jid'); // The jabber_id of your contact
    // You can probably put them in a unordered list and and use their jids as ids.
  });
  App.connection.addHandler(App.on_presence, null, "presence");
  App.connection.send($pres());
}
```

Notice that I added an `on_presence` callback and `connection.send($pres())`. It's purpose is so that you can get updates from your contacts if ever their presence change. Your presence callback will then look like this:

```
on_presence(presence){
  var presence_type = $(presence).attr('type'); // unavailable, subscribed, etc...
  var from = $(presence).attr('from'); // the jabber_id of the contact
  if (presence_type != 'error'){
    if (presence_type === 'unavailable'){
      // Mark contact as offline
    }else{
      var show = $(presence).find("show").text(); // this is what gives away, dnd, etc.
      if (show === 'chat' || show === ''){
        // Mark contact as online
      }else{
        // etc...
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

You can check the Strophe.js [documentation](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.0.2/files2/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Connection.sendIQ) for more information. With sendIQ you can add more parameters like error callbacks, etc.

Hope this helps!

Edit:

Forgive me, I made a mistake. `$(presence).attr('type')` doesn't give you if the contact is online or not but it gives you the presence type. The presence type is actually the signal that tells you if a contact if it is unavailable or if you are subscribed, unsubscribed, etc to your contact.

In the [XMPP Documentation](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html):

> **2.2.1.  Types of Presence**
>
> The 'type' attribute of a presence stanza is OPTIONAL. A presence
>   stanza that does not possess a 'type' attribute is used to signal to
>   the server that the sender is online and available for communication.
>   If included, the 'type' attribute specifies a lack of availability, a
>   request to manage a subscription to another entity's presence, a
>   request for another entity's current presence, or an error related to
>   a previously-sent presence stanza. If included, the 'type' attribute
>   MUST have one of the following values:
>
> - unavailable -- Signals that the entity is no longer available for
>     communication.
> - subscribe -- The sender wishes to subscribe to the
>     recipient's presence.
> - subscribed -- The sender has allowed the
>     recipient to receive their presence.
> - unsubscribe -- The sender is
>     unsubscribing from another entity's presence.
> - unsubscribed -- The
>     subscription request has been denied or a previously-granted
>     subscription has been cancelled. etc...

It is `$(presence).find("show")` gives you the status of your contact. From the docs:

> **2.2.2.1.  Show**
>
> The OPTIONAL  element contains non-human-readable XML character
>   data that specifies the particular availability status of an entity or
>   specific resource. A presence stanza MUST NOT contain more than one
>    element. The  element MUST NOT possess any attributes.
>   If provided, the XML character data value MUST be one of the following
>   (additional availability types could be defined through a
>   properly-namespaced child element of the presence stanza):
>
> - away -- The entity or resource is temporarily away.
> - chat -- The entity or resource is actively interested in chatting.
> - dnd -- The entity or resource is busy (dnd = "Do Not Disturb").
> - xa -- The entity or resource is away for an extended period (xa = "eXtended Away").
>
> If no show element is provided, the entity is assumed to be online and
>   available.

Comment: Awesome answer. Just one more question: Is there any list of possible values in "type" attribute? And others too, respectively? That ones, I can pass to Strophe.addHandler: ns, name, type, id, from, options

Comment: Hi Pavel, I updated my answer because I realized I made a mistake when I read your comment. I added the answers to your questions too, and also a link to the XMPP docs.

Comment: I have followed your snippets above I can't seem to get a list of my roster. What is it that I could possibly be doing wrong

Comment: @RudyJessop it's been quite a few years since I've checked back, you have the `return true` at the end of your handler as the answer below mine pointed out. :)

Answer (score 4):

One important thing to note, is that as [Is it right that Strophe.addHandler reads only first node from response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912530/is-it-right-that-strophe-addhandler-reads-only-first-node-from-response) said, If you want to read more than just the first presence node, make sure to return true at the end, because: "The handler should return true if it is to be invoked again; returning false will remove the handler after it returns."

So the solution I used should look something like this:

```
on_presence(presence){
   var presence_type = $(presence).attr('type'); // unavailable, subscribed, etc...
   var from = $(presence).attr('from'); // the jabber_id of the contact
   if (presence_type != 'error'){
     if (presence_type === 'unavailable'){
        // Mark contact as offline
     }else{
       var show = $(presence).find("show").text(); // this is what gives away, dnd, etc.
       if (show === 'chat' || show === ''){
         // Mark contact as online
       }else{
         // etc...
       }
     }
   }
   //RETURN TRUE!!!!!!!!!
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is true and everyone working with Strophe does this mistake once or twice. However, it is related to all Strophe handlers, not only presence handler.

Comment: I missed the return true. Thanks @RamRovi this solved my problem :)