# Get presence from xmpp using strophe.js after subscribed user invitation

Tags: xmpp, strophe

How to get the get presence from xmpp using strophe.js after subscribed user invitation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling presence in Strophe.js-based chat application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062950/handling-presence-in-strophe-js-based-chat-application)

Comment: initially login time i will establish connection from xmpp and get my friends list in my roster. after that i will send subscribe request to User2. after accepted the request User2, roster have duplicate name or jid displayed. So how to avoid duplicate jid or name after accept subscribed request in User2 roster. Thank you.